# Is it possible to partially revert a merge in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have merged a number of revisions (lets's say 50 to 100) from trunk to branch. I have committed changes from working copy to the branch (rev 101).

Later, I have found out that revisions 80-100 shouldn't have been merged. Usually "Revert changes from these revisions" command from Show log screen works, but now, when I select said revisions (with "Include merged revisions" options turned on) dialog box says merge is finished, but nothing is changed on the working copy.

Is this scenario supported at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can't undo less than one commit
- Mergeset is one commit in branch

From the above follows that for the solution of the problem you **must** to commit *at least one additional* correcting revision

Easy way (2 revisions) - Rollback 101, merge right set from trunk

Hard short way (1 revision) - if you have merged 50:100, but have to have 50:79, you can reverse merge unwanted *trunk's revisions* from *branch head*

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. Problem is in the TSVN client which allows selection of revisions and then does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The scenario is supported for your working copy, and not for the remote branch. TortoiseSVN is made to "never lose data": [Roll back (Undo) revisions in the repository - Appendix B from TortoiseSVN Documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html)

If this reversion is really necessary in the branch, try to delete the branch remotely and create it again.

Comment: This answer misses the point. I don't need to 'lose data', I just want to revert changes from some revisions.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer. You can apply a reverse merge (as explained in the other answer) **or** delete the branch with the undesired revisions and then create another branch. SVN was projected to maintain all data stored, not **to make users lose data**. Read the answer again before simply voting down and allege the answer misses the point.

Comment: 1) "The scenario is supported for your working copy, and not for the remote branch." - I was trying to revert some revisions on my working copy. Read my question again, please. 2) 'TortoiseSVN is made to "never lose data"' - I don't want it to lose data. 3) "Roll back (Undo) revisions in the repository - Appendix B from TortoiseSVN Documentation" - this link exactly describes what I did, but it did not work. I am restoring your answer's vote count but I still think that you did't read the question thoroughly.